# PHP xpath on the result of an xpath with either DOMDocument or SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml, domdocument

I'm trying perform an xpath query on the result of an earlier xpath query. I can write the xpath query to extract the child elements and then iterate over the resulting elements, passing them off to another function for further processing. My problems come when I want to apply another xpath each of those resulting elements.

Given the XML

```
<grandfather>
    <mother>
       <son>1</son>
       <son>2</son>
    </mother>
    <mother>
       <daughter>3</daughter>
    </mother>
    <mother>
       <daughter>4</daughter>
       <son>5</son>
    </mother>
<grandfather>
```

I can get all the mothers with the xpath `/grandfather/mother`, but can I then query those mother nodes, in a separate function, using the passed mother node as the relative root of the next query?

The problem is compounded when the XML has a namespace which you need to register to get the xpath to work. With SimpleXML, the namespace prefix registered before the first xpath query is not retained in the query result, so you have to register it again for subsequent queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument for `DOMXpath::evaluate()` is the context for the expression. Here is a small example working on your xml:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//mother') as $mother) {
  var_dump(
    $xpath->evaluate('count(daughter)', $mother),
    $xpath->evaluate('count(son)', $mother)
  );
}
```

You have to provide the Xpath instance into a function to keep the namespace registration.

It is possible to extend DOMDocument and the other DOMNode classes to allow the registration on the object level. I implemented that in FluentDOM.

Comment: You've answered the question exactly as I've phrased it, so thanks. Unfortunately I'm trying to use different class methods in my code to process different bits of the XML. This means that I have to pass around and return both the DOM document and the xpath with the registered namespace, which is a bit cumbersome, particularly the returning.

Comment: No, you will have to pass around the Xpath instance and the context node(s). The document is available in the `DOMNode::$ownerDocument` property. If you extend the `DOMDocument` you can store the Xpath instance as a property for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a second query on the original xpathDocument, *relative* to your first result-node by using `./` in the start of your query string and using the first result-node as second parameter  :

```
$motherList=$xml->query('/grandfather/mother');
$aMother=$motherList[0];
$daughterList=$xml->query('./daugther',$aMother);
```